# Creating a regular expression that would match a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that would match a string. I am adding a multiple condition, starting with 'f', followed by any number of characters, followed by letter 'a' or the character '-', followed by one or more numeric characters and followed by the letter 'n'

The following examples should return true:

- f2a20n
- f2bfv-2009n
- f2-2000n
- f2bfv-2009na

So far I have researched php regular expression and created this code

```
$a = 'f2bfv-2009n';

$f_search = 'f';
$num_search = '[0-9]';
$or_search = '(a|-)';
$double_number_search = "^[0-9]{1,}$";
$n_search = 'n';

if(preg_match("/{$or_search}{$double_number_search}{$f_search}{$num_search}{$n_search}/i", $a)) {
      echo 'true';
}
```

This should be true but its not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern `(a|-)^[0-9]{1,}$f[0-9]n` which is formed wrongly. You started with `a` or `-` and the line start symbol `^` and end symbol `$` are at the middle position which are wrong. I formed it correctly as per your demand. Try the following [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/yBWJlD/1).

```
$a = 'f2bfv-2009n';
if(preg_match("/^f\w+(a|-)\d+n/i", $a)) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://3v4l.org/iiWYE)

Comment: wow it works. Earlier I tried this method on my own and it didn't work. I must have missed some symbols. Thank you

Comment: I was missing \w+ and \ what do they represent @MH2K9

Comment: `\w+` search for word characters in a string.